# IIS Binding on localhost can't show page

Tags: web-services, iis, binding

I'm trying to set up bindings for two services on localhost IIS but when I attempt to access the URL I get `404` (Page cannot be displayed).

Edit: 
This is purely for testing purposes and not for a release!

**My setup:**

**Service 1:**

- Name: ServiceAdmin.localhost
- Port: `8082`
- Binding setup:Hostname: ServiceAdmin.localhost, Port: `80`

**Service 2:**

- Name: Web.Api
- Port: `8080`
- Binding setup: Hostname: jftapi.com (tried this url for TS Purposes), Port: `80`

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the question myself as I found what the problem was. Maybe a simple thing obvious to most but it might help someone:

The url's (ServiceAdmin.localhost and jftapi.com) needed to be added to the `hosts` file located in `Windows\System32\drivers\etc` as follows:

```
   127.0.0.1       ServiceAdmin.localhost
   127.0.0.1       www.jftapi.com
```

This was what I had missed!

Comment: That might be a wrong answer if you are not in testing phase, as the proper records should be configured at DNS not hosts file.

Comment: You are right. I guess I should have stated that clearly in my question. I am in testing phase and not in any release phase. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my question to clarify!